# Updating saved data in Realtime Database using Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application which allows a user to register their details, log in with them then fill out a questionnaire, these details will also be saved for later use. Current I have successfully got my user's details on the registration page to save however whenever they fill out the questionnaire their registration details are being overwritten with their answers on the questionnaire. Included below is the code for my questionnaire page.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_faqquestions);
        setupUIViews();
        fAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
submitfaq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(validate()){
                sendScoreData();
                            Toast.makeText(faqquestions.this, "Successfully completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(faqquestions.this, Results.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(faqquestions.this, "Submission failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

private void setupUIViews() {
   question1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question1);
    question2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question2);
    question3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question3);
    question4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question4);
    question5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question5);
   question6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question6);
   question7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question7);
   question8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question8);
   question9 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question9);
   question10 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question10);

    submitfaq = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitfaq);



}

private Boolean validate() {
boolean result = false;

questionOne = question1.getText().toString();
questionTwo = question2.getText().toString();
questionThree = question3.getText().toString();
questionFour = question4.getText().toString();
questionFive = question5.getText().toString();
questionSix = question6.getText().toString();
questionSeven = question7.getText().toString();
questionEight = question8.getText().toString();
questionNine = question9.getText().toString();
questionTen = question10.getText().toString();

    if(questionOne.isEmpty() || questionTwo.isEmpty() || questionThree.isEmpty() || questionFour.isEmpty() || questionFive.isEmpty() || questionSix.isEmpty()|| questionSeven.isEmpty() || questionEight.isEmpty() || questionNine.isEmpty() || questionTen.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(faqquestions.this, "Please enter in all feilds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        result = true;
    }
    return  result;
}

private void sendScoreData() {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reff = firebaseDatabase.getReference(fAuth.getUid());
    faqinputs FAQinputs = new faqinputs(questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree, questionFour, questionFive, questionSix, questionSeven, questionEight, questionNine, questionTen);
    reff.setValue(FAQinputs);

}
```

Comment: Yes, your code is currently overwriting the same node each time.  What are you expecting it to do differently?

Comment: I am wanting to update the data for each user when they register their details are stored then I would like to update this data with their questions they have filled out from the questionnaire. Is a Hashmap required to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to [update existing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data) at a location in the database, then you should use [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) which accepts a Map of specific child/value pairs to change at that location.